# WordPress if the_title == null { hide <h2></h2> } else display regular formatting

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to hide WordPress' `the_title` h2 tag if the title is left blank, else it would be to display the title or normal order. Here's the first attempt at coding this:

```
<?php if '' == the_title() {'test'}

    else {

        '<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>'
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just test for the title and only write something if it is there. So:

```
<?php if (the_title()){ // do some stuff with php and the_title() }; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @jory-cunningham So something like:
'code'
<?php if (the_title()){

   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
}; ?>

Comment: Yes, but be careful to either close your php tag or use php echo for literal strings (like your HTML). It looks like you are mixing in HTML strings into your php.

Comment: so like this?
   <?php if (the_title()){ ?>
   
   <h2><a href="'<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   
   <?php endif}; ?>

Comment: You'll need to use `get_the_title()`, not `the_title()` if using it in a conditional like that. `the_title()` echo's the title and will cause problems. So... `<?php if (get_the_title()){ //...etc`

Answer (score 0):

Further to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047066/wordpress-if-the-title-null-hide-h2-h2-else-display-regular-formattin#comment32385108_12047106), I think this needs a complete code snippet as an example as there's some confusion in the original code and in the OP's comments about how to start/end if statements and PHP code blocks.

This should work:

```
<?php
    if (get_the_title()) {
?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php
    }
?>
```